# How to move or resize X11 windows (even if they are maximized)?

Tags: python, linux, shell, window, x11

I want to change position of a window. My problem is that the window can be maximized, this does not allow to change its size and location (window can belong to any application). I use KDE4.

---

I tried to use [ewmh](http://pyewmh.sourceforge.net/ewmh.html) Python module. In my case when the window is maximized I just want to move it from one monitor to the other, keeping it maximized. I need to unmaximize it to set its geometry, so I tried to unmaximize it using `ewmh.setWmState()` to set `_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT`, `_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ` to `0`, then `ewmh.display.flush()`.

Sometimes I can configure the position and size of a previously maximized window, sometimes not. For some reason it does not work reliably, and is especially likely to fail for maximized windows if I just switched from a single-monitor to triple monitors with `xrandr`.

Please note that unmaximizing always works, what (often) does not work is changing window position (or size) afterwards.

---

I also tried doing this in the terminal. This is the easiest way to reproduce my problem. First, get the Window ID (`$WID`) for some maximized window. Then:

```
wmctrl -i -r $WID -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
wmctrl -i -r $WID -e 0,1280,50,1250,1250
```

But the second command does nothing unless I move or resize the window manually before running it. Unlike `ewmh`, `wmctrl` never works as expected if the window is maximized. `wmctrl` unmaximizes the window successfully but cannot change its position or size afterwards.

This is reproducible in both the single and triple monitor X screen states.

This problem seems to be not specific to any particular tool. For example, xdotool also fails to change window size/location if the window was just unmaximized but was not moved/resized manually.

---

The only reliable workaround I have found so far is to unmaximize the window, either manually, with `ewmh` or with `wmctrl`, and then manually change the window size or manually move it a bit. Only then I always can move or resize it with `ewmh` or `wmctrl`. But obviously this is not acceptable solution.

Is there reliable way to set window geometry even if the window is currently maximized? A method through Python is preferred, but a solution with shell commands will be fine too.

Comment: the "emwh" python module you are using seens to be a bit "hidden" (not instalable from pypi with "pip" ) - tellign where did you get it may improve yur chances of getting a proper answer. I found a module with this name inside the "xpybutil" project, which is not building without some tweaks on my system.

Comment: I added the link to ewmh module in my question. It sometimes works as expected, so wmctrl is better for reproducing the problem: if you manage wmctrl -e ... to work (by running some shell command or python code before it), then the problem with ewmh will be solved too. So this question is not about particular module, but about finding reliable way to set geometry for maximized window. Obvious way is to unmaximize window first, but for some reason unmaximized windows tend to ignore attempts to set their geometry (it's like they were still maximized) unless I move/resize them manually first.

Comment: A freshly-unmaximized window for some weird reason cannot be moved or resized programmatically. This behavior is consistent across tools and window managers. Unmapping and then mapping the window back right after unmaximizing seems to help. I don't have a slightest idea why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to n.m. comment I found a solution. Here are  relevant parts from my python [script](https://dragon.studio/2014/05/conwin) (it saves and restores state and geometry of all windows, so this example unmaximizes, unmaps and maps all windows):

```
from time import sleep
from ewmh import EWMH
from Xlib import display, protocol, X
from Xlib.protocol.request import *
...
ewmh = EWMH()
disp = display.Display()
poll_interval = 0.025 # s
poll_attempts_limit = 10
...
def unmaximize(window):
  ewmh.setWmState(window, 0, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT")
  ewmh.setWmState(window, 0, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ")
...
  for client in all_win:
    unmaximize(client.window)
  ewmh.display.flush()
  for client in all_win:
    client.xwin.unmap() 
  poll_attempts = 0
  for client in all_win:
    while client.xwin.get_attributes().map_state == X.IsViewable \
      and poll_attempts < poll_attempts_limit:
      sleep(poll_interval)
      poll_attempts += 1
  for client in all_win:
    client.xwin.map()   
  poll_attempts = 0
  for client in all_win:
    while client.xwin.get_attributes().map_state != X.IsViewable \
      and poll_attempts < poll_attempts_limit:
      sleep(poll_interval)
      poll_attempts += 1
```

After executing this code it is possible to set window geometry for any window. `all_win` is a list of all windows represented as list of custom class objects populated with data from `ewmh.getClientList()`. Each `client.xwin = disp.create_resource_object("window", client.id)`. Waiting for mapping/unmapping to finish is important, otherwise it will be unreliable. Also, it is necessary to limit poll attempts to prevent infinite loop in case some window gets mapped or unmapped unexpectedly.

---

If you do not want to reconfigure a lot of windows at once, there is no noticeable performance improvement from using python xlib module for unmapping and mapping, it is easier to use xdotool instead:

```
from os import system
...
system("xdotool windowunmap --sync " + str(client.window.id))
system("xdotool windowmap   --sync " + str(client.window.id))
```

---

If you want to set window geometry in shell script the following example should work even if the window is maximized:

```
wmctrl -i -r $WID -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
xdotool windowunmap --sync $WID
xdotool windowmap   --sync $WID
wmctrl -i -r $WID -e 0,$x,$y,$width,$height
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full script? I am also working on a layout saving script.

Comment: @godblessfq I fixed the link, please click "script" link in the answer to download it. Please note that the script is old, and was written many years ago. If you improve the script, or write something better, please do not forget to share! Thanks.

Comment: I have made a emacs winner mode like script called eyebrowse.py. The link is https://github.com/qiangF/erofi

Comment: To people trying this out, if the window isn't hidden after it's unmapped, or doesn't show up after it's mapped, try `disp.flush()` each time.